# Why does this not bind?

Tags: angularjs, binding

I'm learning all about angular. I know there's alot of SO questions about Angular binding but I'm still struggling. Maybe some one can give me some clarity with this example.

```
        .controller('myCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){

            //define dummy usermanager "class" 
            var um = function(){
                this.username = 'myUsername';
            };

            //init dummy user class 
            var _um = new um();

            //Bind usermanager to scope 
            $scope.UserManager = _um;

            //After three seconds set new username 
            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log('set');
                _um.username = 'newUsername';
            },3000);
        }]);
```

Using basic template

```
<p>{{ UserManager }}</p>
```

In this example it will always read { username : myUsername } and never change to { username : newUsername }

How can I properly use Angulars two way binding in this example?

**EDIT:**
It appears I can use $scope.$apply(); but that doesn't seem like the best way to do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As others have pointed out, angular does not know about the change in `$scope`. You should use [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) instead which wraps your function in an `$apply`

```
$timeout(function() {
    console.log('set');
     _um.username = 'newUsername';
}, 3000);
```

Comment: The above comment is 100% correct.  When you use angular, you need to use angular's wrapper services b/c it will trigger the apply / digest cycle which is what makes the two way binding work.  Here is a link to all of the angular services.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service.

Comment: Thanks, my question should've been more direct about what I actually want. I was actually dealing with $http, but was trying to simplify the question for clarity's sake. Your answer did help me understand the loop a little better though. You should expand more on the digest cycle for anyone else experiencing this problem [ though I know it's already discussed in many places on SO ]

Answer (score 0):

$scope.UserManager points to the object _um.

When you say _um.username = 'newUsername', this will change the value of the property of the _um object. And if after that you try console.log($scope.UserManager.username) - that will output fine.

However, when you say _um.username = 'newUsername', Angular does not know that in some was it affects data on the scope. So it does not make a refresh on the DOM with new $scope values.

You can invoke this with a $scope.$apply(); 
(would suggest not to)

You can learn about watchers in AngularJS - that might help.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS actually calls almost all of your code within an $apply call. Events like ng-click, controller initialization, $http callbacks are all wrapped in $scope.$apply(). So you don’t need to call it yourself, in fact you can’t. Calling $apply inside $apply will throw an error.

You do need to use it if you are going to run code in a new turn. And only if that turn isn’t being created from a method in the AngularJS library.

Inside that new turn, you should wrap your code in $scope.$apply(). setTimeout will execute a function in a new turn after a delay. Since Angular doesn’t know about that new turn, the update will not be reflected.

so your solution is use $scope.$apply is completely appropriate.

```
            $scope.$apply(function(){
                _um.username = 'newUsername';
            })
```